# The argument type 'Stream<MyUser?>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Stream<MyUser?>?'

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to create a user system in my mobile app.

For this cause, I defined my user model as below:

```
class MyUser {
  final String? uid;

  MyUser({this.uid});
}
```

And I defined my authentication as following. I just use the basic firebase commands.

```
class AuthService {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance; //private data member

  //create MyUser object based on FirebaseUser
  MyUser? _userfromFirebase(User user) {
    return user != null ? MyUser(uid: user.uid) : null;
  }

  //auth change user stream
  Stream<MyUser?> get user {
    return _auth
        .authStateChanges()
        .map((User? user) => _userfromFirebase(user!));
  }

  //sign in with email & password
  Future signInWithMail() async {
    try {} catch (e) {}
  }

  //register with email & password

  //sign out
}
```

Then, I tried to pull the current user information in another component by calling `AuthService().user` but I got the error below.

```
The argument type 'Stream<MyUser?>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Stream<MyUser?>?'.
```

I tried to call this code in the main.dart. But unfortunately I couldn't make it work. You can see my main.dart in below. How can I fix this error?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:unistuff_main/screens/wrapper.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:unistuff_main/services/auth.dart';
import 'package:unistuff_main/models/myuser.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamProvider<MyUser?>.value(
      initialData: null,
      value: AuthService().user,
      child: MaterialApp(
        home: Wrapper(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello, What AuthService().user returns ?

Comment: Hi, sorry. I added the auth.dart file in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Library URIs are case sensitive.  AuthService imports MyUser from `MyUser.dart`, while MyApp imports MyUser from `myuser.dart`.  Even though these are the same file (assuming a case-insensitive file system), they are considered different libraries, so the types don't match.

You will need to change one of the import statements to match the other.

Comment: The other answers concentrate on the difference between nullable and non-nullable types, but it is perfectly valid to provide a `Foo` where a `Foo?` is expected.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the type of your `AuthService().user` isn't null-able, so try to change the type of the user from your auth.dart to Stream<MyUser?>?.

```
Stream<MyUser?>? get onAuthStateChanges => FirebaseAuth.instance
  .authStateChanges()
  .map((currentUser) => MyUser.fromSnapshot(currentUser!));
```

I'm not sure, but you probably are using the `authStateChanges()` from `FirebaseAuth.instance`. So if it doesn't solve your problem, print the `AuthService().user` :)

Comment: I added the auth.dart file to post, so sorry for forgotting it. I add the extra "?" symbol to near the <MyUser?> But It didnt change the error :( Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In the line when error occurs, try to use operator ?? and pass the raw object if null.

For example:

```
MyObject(
  stringField: myString ?? '', //you are ensuring that if your String is null, there will be no error
);
```

Comment: I tried to add"??" into the line but It didn't change anything much. To specific error is right in the "value: AuthService().user," line. Thank you for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
Stream<MyUser?> get user {
    return _auth
        .authStateChanges()
        .map((User? user) => _userfromFirebase(user!));
  }
```

Write:

```
Stream<MyUser?> get user {
  return _auth.authStateChanges().map(_userFromFirebaseUser);
}
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?